# Specifying a flex-config.xml with Maven / Flex Mojos

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2

I have to port an existing project to Maven, and it includes a resource called "config.xml" that is copied to the deploy directory alongside the SWF and HTML, and loaded at run-time to locate a bunch of WSDLs.

Flex Mojos has taken it upon itself to assume that my xml file is a flex-config file with instructions for the compiler, which of course promptly gives up the ghost.

The question is: How do I specify a named config file for the compiler so that Maven stops this nonsense (as well as specifying my compile-time options)?

Comment: Are you using http://sites.sonatype.org/flexmojos/flexmojos-maven-plugin/project-summary.html ? May be you can give a pom example may be than someone is able to help...

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your pom showing how you include your config file?

Comment: Current state of the POM file is here:

http://pastie.textmate.org/private/wlsfrn23dievr7ydpoj3w

I started with the archetype, and then added and changed things until it would compile, so it's probably all sub-optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<configuration>
     <configFile>path/to/yourConfigFile.xml</configFile>
</configuration>
```

https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/compile-swf-mojo.html#compile-swf-mojo.html-configFile

Comment: Where am I supposed to put the configuration element? The docs don't help unless you're already a Maven expert :-/

Comment: After experimenting some, it seems it goes into the build/plugins/plugin element for flexmojos-maven-plugin, not in something specific to flexmojos:generate-config-swf

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the archeology. If you want to hide only some warnings, you can add the following in your pom:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Maven is more strict than Flash Builder, so I'm hiding some warnings -->
    <compilerWarnings>
        <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>
    </compilerWarnings>
</configuration>
```

From [this documentation](http://georgik.sinusgear.com/wp-content/flex/flexmojos.txt):

```
compilerWarnings
  A list of warnings that should be enabled/disabled
  Equivalent to -compiler.show-actionscript-warnings,
  -compiler.show-binding-warnings,
  -compiler.show-shadowed-device-font-warnings,
  -compiler.show-unused-type-selector-warnings and -compiler.warn-*
  Usage:
  <compilerWarnings>
    <show-actionscript-warnings>true</show-actionscript-warnings>
    <warn-bad-nan-comparison>false</warn-bad-nan-comparison>
  </compilerWarnings>
```